# Subordonnée comme sujet?

Tags: grammaire, paroles-de-chanson

Les paroles d'une chanson d’Angèle commencent par :

> N'existe pas sans son contraire qui lui semble facile à trouver.

Je ne comprends pas la construction de cette phrase. Je ne peux pas trouver son sujet. Je pense que la subordonnée doit être le sujet, mais selon cette supposition je ne suis pas capable de traduire la proposition. Je suis très incertain. Je pense que ça veut dire quelque chose comme

> Whatever seems to him to be easily findable, does not exist without its opposite.

Mais pour moi, c'est dur de saisir le sens de sa phrase.

Est-ce-que vous pouvez expliquer la construction, et traduire la proposition en anglais?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est une figure de style, et il manque le sujet dans cette phrase. Je pense qu'on ne peut pas la comprendre telle quelle.

Elle veut dire :

> [Le bonheur] n'existe pas sans son contraire, qui lui semble facile à trouver.

À mons avis, c'est pour camoufler un peu le sujet de la chanson, pour qu'on ne soit pas capable à la première écoute de comprendre de quoi elle parle. Une phrase un peu cryptique ça pousse à écouter le reste de la chanson pour mieux comprendre.

Comment: Il faudrait aussi lever l'ambiguïté de la deuxième partie qui ne signifie pas ***that seems to him easily findable*** mais ***that, on the opposite, is easy to find (by anyone)***.